# AngularJS geração de PDF

Tags: angularjs, pdf

Bom dia.

Estou trabalhando com angularjs versão 1.5, e estou tendo problemas para gerar PDF.
O response recebe um array de byte gostaria de alguma ajuda.

```
this.TesteService.relatorio().$promise.then((response) => {
        console.log('response',response);
        var array = Object.values(response);
        console.log('array',array);
        var file = new Blob(array, {type: 'application/pdf'});
        console.log('file',file);
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        console.log('fileURL',fileURL);
        this.$window.open(fileURL);
    });
```

Como faço atualmente exibe as folhas do arquivo mas elas estão em branco e ocorre o erro:

> Error: Command token too long: 128

Comment: Tenta assim: `var pdfAsDataUri = "data:application/pdf;base64,"+array ;
window.open(pdfAsDataUri);`

Comment: Não deu certo, é aberta uma nova janela mas não aparece nada. Como faço atualmente exibe as folhas do arquivo mas elas estão em branco e ocorre o erro Error: Command token too long: 128

Comment: Adicione essa informação a pergunta. Ao que parece esse erro que você relatou é um bug do `Acrobat Reader`

Comment: Certo vou adicionar.

Answer (score 1):

Ola depois de muita pesquisa, e sugestões em outros locais descobri o problema e uma solução.

1- O problema - Meu método de consulta retornava uma String base64 do meu back-end que ao chegar no then se tornava um Objeto composto de chave(número sequencial) e valor(uma carácter da minha String) e mesmo convertendo em array não dava certo.

2- A solução - Eu ainda não sei porque ocorre a transformação descrita acima mas uma das soluções que achei foi:

```
$http({
    url: url,
    method: tipoRequest,
    data: param
})
.success((response) => {
    download('data:' + tipoArquivo + ';base64,' + response, nomeArquivo, tipoArquivo);
})
.error((response) => {
    console.log('error',response);
});
```

Utilizei uma lib chamada [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html) para controle, ajudou bastante.

Existema outras formas de resolvem para mim essa já serviu, gostaria se possível que alguem me explica-se porque o a situação que descrevi no item 1 ocorre.

Agradeço a ajuda.